# How to access a list of matched value programmatically base on user current input - jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this array

```
["ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"]
```

I have reproduce it right here : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/Lsubhxmv/

When I typed `"P"` - I see this listed

[image]

Expected Result

```
console.log(matchedValues), I should see ['ActionScript','AppleScript','Asp','Lisp','Perl','PHP','Python']
```

---

as soon as I typed `"Py"` only one come up

[image]

Expected Result

```
console.log(matchedValues), I should see ['Python']
```

---

I need to access a list of **matched** value programmatically base on user current input.

Comment: Thank you for improving the question. This is much more clear than the previous one.

Comment: Thank you guys for the amazing feedback, time, and effort for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`response`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event of the AutoComplete to retrieve the filtered values:

```js
$(".search").autocomplete({
  source: ["ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang"
    // other values...
  ],
  response: function(e, ui) {
    console.log(ui);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" class="search" />
```